# Istio-pilot Consul Support

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

It's been a little unclear to me what requirements Istio-pilot using Consul adapter are. I am trying to setup and have istio-pilot Discovery to act as pure Envoy xDS. However, in one of the examples where Consul is used (from Istio src), it does install one kube-apiserver (and etcd for that matter). I would like to use Envoy as the data-plane (or istio-pilot agent for that matter), but leverage Consul for service discovery, and not integrate with Kubernetes. Does istio-pilot require K8 anyway for that use case?

Answer (score 0):

Istio supports several different so called ServiceDiscovery implementations.
Kubernetes is one of them which discovers Services from Kubernetes Services.

But this is really just one of the possible ways to run Istio Pilot and you can use other ServiceDiscovery mechanisms line Consul via the command line argument `--registries Consul`.
See https://archive.istio.io/v1.4/docs/reference/commands/pilot-discovery/ for a detailed description of the command line arguments.

Once you run Pilot with that configuration it should load Services exclusively from Consul. These should be pushed to the data plane under the usual name `<service name>.service.consul`.

UPDATE:

From your comment below it seems that you not only want to not load Services from Kubernetes, but in general completely run without it.

While this indeed doesn't seem to be possible with 1.4 – i.e. watching Istio resources is always started – it seems to work with 1.5.

To achieve that you to start pilot with `--disable-install-crds` and `--configDir
<config path>` where `<config path>` points to a directory containing the yamls for the Istio specific resources that you might still need, like Sidecars, MeshPolicy, EnvoyFilter etc. 
If `--configDir` is not defined Pilot will still try to get these resources from Kubernetes, so it is essential to add this argument even if the directory is empty.

Finally you should make sure that the MeshConfig that you pass to pilot via `--meshConfig meshconfig.yaml` does not point to a URL of galley by commenting this out, in case you copied an existing file `/etc/istio/config/mesh` from a running instance of Pilot:

```yaml
configSources:
#- address: istio-galley.istio-system.svc:9901
#  tlsSettings:
#    mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing and it does contact Consul and get services from the catalog. However, I still see a bunch of attempts to sync Kubernetes controllers, flooding logs. I also use `--disable-install-crds`, which works well because it does not try to install it, but I cannot stop sync. Looking at https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/install/consul/templates/istio.yaml.tmpl#L17 the example installs `kube-apiserver` and my tests, I can just assume you can use an alternative service discovery, it does need Kubernetes apiserver to make it work well.